# Is there a difference between putting dispose on the first line and putting it on the last line?

Tags: flutter, dart

What is the difference between the two code blocks?

First code block

```
  TextEditingController textEditingController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    textEditingController.dispose();
  }
```

second code block

```
  TextEditingController textEditingController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  void dispose() {
    textEditingController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`super.dispose()` should always be the last line in the overrided dispose function, because you should deactivate your specific widget before deactivating the super class widgets.
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/dispose.html